# SQL: Select the names of people who have lended the same books as one specific person

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables in a library database:
Readers(ReaderID, Surname)
Lended(BookID, ReaderID)
I need to find all readers who have borrowed the same books as reader with the surname 'John' and only print their surnames. The following code is what I have so far. I think it counts the amount of same books correctly but I can't get it to count the entries of 'John' in the l2 table in order to compare that count to the books in common with other readers. No subqueries/subselects are allowed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  r1.surname     --, COUNT(l2.readerid),COUNT(l1.readerid) -- used to see how many of the
                                                                          -- book ids are the same
FROM readers r1
JOIN lended l1
   ON r1.readerid=l1.readerid
JOIN reader r2
   ON r1.readerid<>r2.readerid 
JOIN lended l2
   ON l2.readerid=r2.readerid  
   AND l2.bookid=l1.bookid
WHERE
(
    (l2.surname='John')
)
GROUP BY r1.surname
```

Example Readers data:

```
ReaderID    Surname
1           Lilly
2           John
3           Mike
4           Kelly
5           George
```

Example Lended data:

```
BookID    ReaderID
1         1
2         1
3         1
1         2
2         2
1         3
2         3
1         4
4         5
5         5
```

Expected output:

```
Mike
```

Additional explanation to the expected output:

```
John has read books 1 and 2 
Lilly has read books 1, 2 and 3 // one more book compared to John
Kelly has only read book 1 // one less book compared to John
Mike has read books 1 and 2 // exactly the same books as John
George has read books 4 and 5// same amount as John, but not in his list of read books
```

Comment: Homework, nice! Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I hope the edit provided what you needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Contradiction: `l2.bookid<>l1.bookid AND l2.bookid=l1.bookid`

Comment: Redundant: `ON r1.readerid<>r2.readerid AND l1.readerid<>r2.readerid`

Comment: It is supposed to match *all* the books or just *any* of the books?

Comment: @shawnt00 all of the books read by John should be matched

Comment: It also looks like *only* those by John and no others.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yep, in this case only those by John.

Comment: @IvayloMarinov please check your expectation you described and the expected output data you marked in the example. Those are contradictory. So please edit the expectation statement or the desired sample result set.

Comment: @Raihan I can't find the contradiction in my expectation description so I added additional  explanation to the output at the end. Hope that helps.

Comment: Now it's good. Thanks @IvayloMarinov

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, the syntax is per Oracle DB:-

```
With r1 as (
Select l.bookid 
From reader r , lended l
Where r.readerid = l.readerid
And r.surname =‘John’)
Select r2.surname
From reader r2 , r1, lended l1
Where r2.readerid = l1.readerid
AND l1.bookid = r1.bookid
```

Comment: The query itself works, but does not match the expected output (it is the same as in my query). The output using the given example data would look as follows:


    Lilly
    Lilly
    John
    John
    Mike 
    Mike
    Kelly.
So for each of the books that matches Johns books the name is printed once.

Comment: One approach would be using LISTAGG function in oracle here is the reference https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#listagg. Make a concatenated String of all bookid for all readers. Something like 1,2,3. Then do an exact comparison of this new string with other John.